# How to Save a NSString in a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have opened gallery on a BUTTON click and choose an image.I save image full path
in a string.Now How can i save that string in button.I have to save string into a button so that button can hold the path.I have so many buttons like same in my view.and have to perform the same.The code I have used for saving Image path is written below.

// Get the image from the result

```
UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Get the data for the image as a PNG
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

// Give a name to the file
NSString * imageName = @"Myimage.png";

// Now, we have to find the documents directory so we can save it
// Note that you might want to save it elsewhere, like the cache directory,
// or something similar.
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Now we get the full path to the file
NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

// and then we write it out
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

    Button = fullPathToFile; ///This is the button

return;
```

Comment: Not very useful code as their is no *context* provided.  In other words *where* is that code in your app?  Does it have access to the button instances?  Have you provided outlets for the buttons?

Comment: See I have a button.and on a button click .I have open gallery of iPhone.there i choose a image.and save full image path in NSString * fullpathTofile…Now how can i save this string into a button.So that my button can hold the image path.

Comment: I cannot tell you that as you have not provided enough information (and I defy anyone else to provide a definitive answer at this stage).  It's not important how you get the name of the image (we can assume you are doing that correctly).  What is important is what method the code you posted within?  Please provide more code.

Comment: Why you want to save image name to button?

Comment: i don't want to saver image name to a button..I want to save Image path to a button…How a button can hold image path in it ..

Comment: Believe me: you don't want to do that. That is a violation of the MVC pattern and you would be fighting the cocoa framework.

Comment: Hello vikingosegundo/Then how can i save jt.Any other way

Comment: Zaph got the right answer. but I am sure, it does not help you very much, as I think you didn't familiarise yourself with [MVC pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html). But this is crucial to understand apple's frameworks. it'd required programming lessons to teach you this, but that is out of the scope what can be done on stackoverflow. so get yourself a good learning resource. i.e. the stanford cp193 course on iTunes U is great.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution to add property to an object like UIButton etc.

UIButton+String.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton (String)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *path;

@end
```

UIButton+String.m

```
#import "UIButton+String.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton (String)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY;

@dynamic path;

-(void)setPath:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY, path, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSString *)path {
     return (NSString*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY);
}


@end
```

Comment: if `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` will be used, subclassing won't help, as another subclass will be created

Comment: He want save path in a button...this is the solution

Comment: my comment was the answer to an comment that is gone now. and your solution might be right in the context of the question, but will lead to a terrible design. I have to brace myself not to vote down.

Comment: I think the same..the design is bad, if he can, should change that..but if not..this is a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class, that is a class that has the necessary methods and properties to persist the data, add, delete and obtain the data. The model class can be a singleton to allow app wide access if necessary.

Views should just be used to display or to obtain user input.